# Validation Accuracity isn't changing

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I trained my first categorical image classifier, but due I´m new to deep learning, I don't notice what is happening with my validation set. I´m doing a 5 Fold CV, and in each fold, I split the data set into train/validation/test.

After the split, I apply data augmentation in x_train:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=90,
    horizontal_flip=True)
```

Then fit my model with the generator:

```
    history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=25),
                                  validation_data=(x_validation,y_validation), 
                                  steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(len(x_train) / batch),
                                  epochs=epochs)
```

Params: `len(x_train)=31` and `batch=1` cause I want sgd batch.

The data set has 76 images spplited into test=15, Train=31 and Validation=30.

After running this for 5 fold it gives me this graphic:

[image]

What is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, could you provide the architecture of your network?
At first glance it seems that your model is underfitting. Thats why you have high train acc and low val acc. This can have many reasons (e.g. a low number of trainingdata). To help we could need a little more input like what do you want to predict or how the architecture of the network looks like.

Comment: That´s the architecture of my network: https://codeshare.io/GkWLbM I use Resnet50, finetuning all the layers with imagenet weights and then I remove the last layer to create a new one who classifies in 3 classes.

Comment: I have 76 images in the dataset, which is divided into 3 classes. The dataset is  unbalanced because first class have like 52% of the data, and others have 28% and the other 20%

Comment: First of all i would suggest you try to get more data. You use 31 datapoint from your dataset of 76 as train data. That's a very low number of training data. Furthermore if your dataset is unbalanced you could have trainingsdata which is missing one of the classes (we would need the code where you load the data).
If more data doesn't do the trick and you accounted for the class imbalance (e.g. with Over-/Undersampling or weighting) I suggest to share more code and maybe some sample data so we can reproduce the error

Comment: Okey thanks Fabian, I´m trying right now data augmentation but it seems that isn't well implemented so I´m researching how it works.